# Enforcing java annotations at compile time

Tags: java, compilation, annotations

Hi : I wanted to make sure that an annotation is present at compile time in a class.  Is this possible ?  I realize that annoataions are, themselves, classes, so I assume so - but Im just not sure syntactically where and how to enforce/implement such a structure in my classes.

Comment: I have often seen annotation checkers used as part of a unit test suite.  Would this work for you?

Comment: Well -- i have some constants that need to be gotten from classes.  The classes have an ugly constructor, so I cant enforce them using getters.   So i figured I would annotate the class using annotations with the constant parameters as annotation fields.

Answer (score 16):

You can write an annotation processor to run arbitrary logic at compile time.

From an annotation processor, you can do things like check whether a class has a particular structure or member present if a particular annotation exists on that class.  They are pretty flexible - for more of an idea of what you can do with them check out [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html).  They are also supported in major IDEs such as Eclipse and Netbeans.

An introduction to writing an annotation processor is [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html) (link dead, partial copy [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2072018/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-apis.html)).

Comment: This is a good answer.  I'll wait to see if there is a higher level or simpler approach (i.e. a way to simply enforce this in existing code/classes).

Comment: From what I can tell, the annotation processor will omit processing on classes that do not already have the annotations, which does not seem to be what the OP is looking for.  I'm looking for the same solution though, so if I am wrong, I would love an example.

Comment: If you use @SupportedAnnotationTypes("*") on your processor then it will pick up all classes, even if there are no annotations on it.

Comment: @prunge I (almost) love you!, thanks for your comment

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Found link to a part of that original article which is now dead and added it.  It only has the first part, but probably enough to have a good intro still on annotation processors.  There are probably better annotation processor tutorials out there, so those interested search around.