# Java Annotation Processing Tool @NoNull

Tags: java, apt

I want to create an annotation that restricts a developer from specifying *null* as a parameter, which has been annotated with *@NoNull*

For example, if I create this method:

```
public void printLine(@NoNull String line) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

On a method call, I want an error to appear if the user specifies *null* for *line*: `printLine(null);`

I have been using APT for only a little bit of time, and am wondering how to do this (if possible)?

This is the annotation I have created so far:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface NoNull {}
```

Comment: Have you considered looking at other implementations?

Comment: I have never seen an implementation of _@NoNull_. Do you mind linking them?

Comment: There are plenty of `@NotNull`/`@NonNull` annotations, can't you use one of them ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use . Some of them are used by your IDE (IntelliJ for instance) to reports bug, I think that the last Eclipse too, there is findbugs also.

Comment: @Alex The point isn't to use the annotation only for readability, but to _enforce_ the annotation at compile-time with APT.

Comment: Check out this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981540/enforcing-java-annotations-at-compile-time on writing an annotation processor.

Comment: @RNJ, I have read tutorials on using APT, but I need help to specifically make an _@NoNull_ processor.

Comment: You'd need to find every location where the method is called, track every parameter passed to the method, see if you can even *determine* if it's null or not, and take it from there. Good luck!

Comment: I need to know how to search through method calls. Is there a way with APT or reflection... or some other library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile time will be tough to check, since you're really dealing with runtime values.  If you want to create annotations to automatically add code to check this stuff, you should look at project lombok:

http://projectlombok.org/

It uses an annotation processor to add code to your beans to do various things.

For example:

```
@Getter @Setter
private int id;
```

The annotation processor would automatically add get/set methods to your bean.

I don't think it has null checks, but you should be able to add this in and contribute it.

Another option is to use the validation jsr, though this requires you to explicitly validate at runtime, but you could accomplish this with proxies or AOP.

```
@NotNull @Min(1)
public void setId(Integer id)
```

Answer (score 2):

> The point isn't to use the annotation only for readability, but to enforce the annotation at compile-time with APT

Considering that null is a runtime artifact, I don't see how you will enforce a null check at "compile time."

Instead, you'll have to modify your classes, and *apt* is not the tool to do this, at least not by itself. It exists to extract information about annotated elements from source files. But to enforce your `@Null` restriction, you need to modify the running class.

One thing that you could do is use *apt* to extract information about annotated parameters, then use a tool like *aspectj* to modify those classes at runtime to check the parameter value.

But that's a topic that's way too broad for a single SO question.

Comment: I do not need to modify the classes at runtime. If I can iterate through all method calls (and access their parameter values), I can simply print an error message.

Comment: @Thomas - and how will you determine that the variable being passed to a method is null or not? What if that variable is set based on data read from a file?

Comment: If you're just trying to find if any method in the chain is has a different annotation, then you still need to examine the bytecode of all callers of the annotated method, to find how they set the arguments to the annotated method.

Comment: something like this, I'd imagine.


    for (MethodCall call : methodCalls) {
        for (Parameter parameter : filter(call.getParameters(), annotatedWithNoNull) {
            if (parameter.getValue() == null) {
                  processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.ERROR, "Cannot pass null as this parameter);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: You can't tell at compile time whether a variable is going to be null or not.  You can tell if a method is being _explicitly_ called with null as an argument, but that really doesn't help anyone very much.

Answer (score 0):

@Nullable, @Nonnull are locating in package: javax.annotation

Checkout guava, its got some nice things are type safety:
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained

Comment: This is not **compile-time checked** with APT.